# How to create Empty redis stream?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis-reactive

Is possible to create empty stream using spring redis data?
Am trying to create rest endpoint to create just stream without data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `XGROUP CREATE` command with `MKSTREAM` option, to create an empty stream:

```
xgroup create s g $ mkstream
```

If you don't need the group, you can destroy it manually:

```
xgroup destroy s g
```

Another solution is to create a stream with `XADD` command, and then use `XDEL key id` to remove the newly created entry. In this case, the stream will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

You can XADD with MAXLEN = 0. Like this:

```
XADD mystream MAXLEN = 0 * key value
```

Comment: This will create a stream that cannot hold any messages because MAXLEN=0

Comment: Nope. You can always add new elements. With MAXLEN=0, new element added to the stream will be removed and you'll end up with an empty stream.